# finding multiples of a number in Python

Tags: python, math, range

I'm trying to write a code that lets me find the first few multiples of a number. This is one of my attempts:

```
def printMultiples(n, m):
for m in (n,m):
    print(n, end = ' ')
```

I figured out that, by putting `for m in (n, m):`, it would run through the loop for whatever number was `m`.

```
def printMultiples(n, m):
'takes n and m as integers and finds all first m multiples of n'
for m in (n,m):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        while n < 0:
            print(n)
```

After multiple searches, I was only able to find a sample code in java, so I tried to translate that into python, but I didn't get any results. I have a feeling I should be using the `range()` function somewhere in this, but I have no idea where.

Comment: What are `n` and `m` here?

Comment: Kindly show an example of usage and expected results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're trying to find the first `count` multiples of `m`, something like this would work:

```
def multiples(m, count):
    for i in range(count):
        print(i*m)
```

Alternatively, you could do this with range:

```
def multiples(m, count):
    for i in range(0,count*m,m):
        print(i)
```

Note that both of these start the multiples at `0` - if you wanted to instead start at `m`, you'd need to offset it by that much:

```
range(m,(count+1)*m,m)
```

Comment: After messing around with this code, I was able to get it to work exactly how I needed it. Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 4):

Does this do what you want?

```
print range(0, (m+1)*n, n)[1:]
```

For m=5, n=20

```
[20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
```

Or better yet,

```
>>> print range(n, (m+1)*n, n)
[20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
```

For Python3+

```
>>> print(list(range(n, (m+1)*n, n)))
[20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
```

Comment: I tried this out but this was the result:
`>>> printMultiples(10,2)
range(10, 30, 10)
>>> printMultiples(10, 10)
range(10, 110, 10)`

Comment: @iKyriaki It's probably cause he's using Python 2 and you're using Python 3. You can fix it by doing `print([i for i in range(n, (m+1)*n, n)])` instead. I believe it's cause `range()` returns a listin Python 2. In Python 3, `range()` uses `yield` so it's an iterator. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Mahi, in py3, the `range` return a generator.  You can exhaust the generator by wrapping it with `list()`

Comment: @sberry Yes, of course a generator since it uses `yield`, silly me. Good one with the `list()`, haven't ever really thought of that.

Answer (score 4):

Based on mathematical concepts, I understand that:

- all natural numbers that, divided by `n`, having `0` as remainder, are all multiples of `n`

Therefore, the following calculation also applies as a solution (multiples between 1 and 100):

```
>>> multiples_5 = [n for n in range(1, 101) if n % 5 == 0]
>>> multiples_5
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100]
```

For further reading:

- https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/natural-number.html
- https://www.mathwizz.com/arithmetic/help/help9.htm
- https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/multiples.php

Answer (score 2):

For the first ten multiples of 5, say

```
>>> [5*n for n in range(1,10+1)]
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Can you please add more descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
def mul_table(n,i=1):
    print(n*i)
    if i !=10:
        mul_table(n,i+1)
mul_table(7)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you are looking for -

To find all the multiples between a given number and a limit

```py
def find_multiples(integer, limit):
    return list(range(integer,limit+1, integer))
```

This should return -

```
Test.assert_equals(find_multiples(5, 25), [5, 10, 15, 20, 25])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method that can be done is trying to make a list. Here's my example for getting the first 20 multiples of 7.

**Input:**

```
multiples_7 = [x * 7 for x in range(1,21)] 

print(multiples_7)
```

**Output:**

```
[7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 77, 84, 91, 98, 105, 112, 119, 126, 133, 140]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def multiples(n,m,starting_from=1,increment_by=1):
    """
    # Where n is the number 10 and m is the number 2 from your example. 
    # In case you want to print the multiples starting from some other number other than 1 then you could use the starting_from parameter
    # In case you want to print every 2nd multiple or every 3rd multiple you could change the increment_by 
    """
    print [ n*x for x in range(starting_from,m+1,increment_by) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For first 10 multiples of 5 you can do as

```
import numpy as np
#np.arange(1,11) array from 1 to 10 
array_multipleof5 = [5*n for n in np.arange(1,11)]
array_multipleof5 = np.array(array_multipleof5)
print(array_multipleof5)
```

Answer (score 0):

How to calculate the first n multiples of a given number x, in the compact python's lambda notation

```
n_multiples_of_x = lambda n,x : list( range(x, x*n + 1, x) )
```

Tests:

```
assert n_multiples_of_x(5, 5) == [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```